# Cast from interface to specific class with DbSet

Tags: c#, entity-framework, casting

Let's say I've the following code:

```
public interface IInterface
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Foo : IInterface
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Bar : IInterface
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

///

public class Service
{
    private List<Foo> MyList();
    public IQueryable<Foo> GetObjects()
    {
        return MyList().AsQueryable();
    }

    public IQueryable<Bar> GetObjectsFromBD()
    {
        return Entities.Bar;
    }
}
```

And here's how I'll use it

```
public IQueryable<IInterface> GetFooBars()
{
    var foobars = new IQueryable<IInterface>();
    if(someStuff)
        foobars = service.GetObjects(); /*From cache*/
    else
        foobars = service.GetObjectsFromBD(); /*From DbSet*/
    return foobars;
}
```

For some reason, I want to do specific treatment later if the source is the DB or not. So I try to cast as Foo

```
var query = GetFooBars();
var casted = query as IQueryable<Foo>;
if(casted == null) /*Coming from DB*/
    /*Some conditions*/
else /*Coming from cache*/
    /*Some other conditions*/
```

But for some reason that I ignore `casted` is always null, no matter if it comes from the DB or not.

If I try do debug with some `query.GetType()`, it yields

```
 System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[MyNamespace.IInterface]
```

What did I miss? How can I achieve what I want to do without enumerate the query?

Comment: An `IQueryable<IInterface>` is *not* an `IQueryable<Foo>`. It's something whose contents *could* be used as `Foo`. Use `Cast<Foo>` or `OfType<Foo>`

Comment: With code you provided it should work fine and `cached` should be not null when you expect. You need to find out why underlying type is `DbQuery<IInterface>` and not `DbQuery<Foo>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem: to check if the query is coming from the database, you need to check against `DbQuery`, not `IQueryable` (since both methods return a `IQueryable`, but only the database method returns a `DbQuery`):

```
var query = GetFooBars();
var casted = query as DbQuery<Foo>;
if(casted == null) // *not* from database!
```

Second problem: your method doesn't return a `DbQuery<Foo>` or even a `IQueryable<Foo>` - it returns a `IQueryable<IInterface>`. While your collection is actually a collection of `Foo`s, the type system doesn't know that. So the correct code would be:

```
var query = GetFooBars();
var casted = query as DbQuery<IInterface>;
if(casted == null) //...
```

Comment: So I wasn't looking at the correct direction. Thanks